# Android and Eclipse: Sticky debug mode

Tags: android, debugging

I am debugging some code on an Android device. I am starting the debugger from Eclipse.

From time to time I find that when I ask for the app to run regularly (without the debugger) the device still seems to come up in debug mode.

Troubleshooting that I've tried: exiting an re-launching eclipse; Killing the app from the Android device's shell.

Neither of those troubleshooting steps work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem recently. I manually uninstalled my misbehaving app from the device and also rebooted the phone. Either one of those did the trick and the app started running normally.